# EPERM: Operation not permitted - NPM Angular 7 on IIS with backend .Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, node.js, angular, rest, npm

Hi guys i've made an angular 7 app with visual studio 2017. 
So i got AWS machine on windows 10 with IIS.

When i loaded the app, i got this error:

> AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the
>   Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: Error:
>   EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir
>   'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm'
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

So the image with the iis error return:

[image]

Complete text error:

```
   An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm'

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:78:20
at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:228:22)
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:266:24
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:83:7
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:82:13
at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:173:20)
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:47:53
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205
if (npm.config.get('json')) {
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)
at process.emit (events.js:189:13)
at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:496:27)
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm'

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:78:20
at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:228:22)
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:266:24
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:83:7
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:82:13
at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:173:20)
at Conf.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:229:20)
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205

if (npm.config.get('json')) {

^


TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)

at process.emit (events.js:189:13)

at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:496:27)

))
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.GetResultCore(bool waitCompletionNotification)

InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm'

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:78:20
at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:228:22)
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:266:24
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:83:7
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:82:13
at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:173:20)
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:47:53
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205
if (npm.config.get('json')) {
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)
at process.emit (events.js:189:13)
at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:496:27)
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm'

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:78:20
at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:228:22)
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:266:24
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:83:7
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:82:13
at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:173:20)
at Conf.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:229:20)
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205

if (npm.config.get('json')) {

^


TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)

at process.emit (events.js:189:13)

at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:496:27)

Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(string sourcePath, string npmScriptName, ILogger logger)

Stack Query Cookies Headers
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm' 
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined 
 at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18) at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:78:20 at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:228:22) at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:266:24 at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:83:7 at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:82:13 at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25) at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:173:20) at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:47:53 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205
 if (npm.config.get('json')) {
 ^

 TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
 at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)
 at process.emit (events.js:189:13)
 at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:496:27)
 Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm' 
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined 
 at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18) at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:78:20 at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:228:22) at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:266:24 at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:83:7 at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:82:13 at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25) at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:173:20) at Conf.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:229:20) C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205

 if (npm.config.get('json')) {

 ^


 TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

 at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)

 at process.emit (events.js:189:13)

 at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:496:27)

 ))
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.GetResultCore(bool waitCompletionNotification)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Util.TaskTimeoutExtensions.WithTimeout<T>(Task<T> task, TimeSpan timeoutDelay, string message)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext context, HttpClient httpClient, Task<Uri> baseUriTask, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken, bool proxy404s)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SpaProxyingExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass2_0+<<UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer>b__0>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Show raw exception details
InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm' 
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined 
 at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18) at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:78:20 at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:228:22) at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:266:24 at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:83:7 at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:82:13 at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25) at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:173:20) at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:47:53 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205
 if (npm.config.get('json')) {
 ^

 TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
 at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)
 at process.emit (events.js:189:13)
 at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:496:27)
 Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm' 
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined 
 at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18) at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:78:20 at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:228:22) at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:266:24 at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:83:7 at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:82:13 at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25) at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:173:20) at Conf.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:229:20) C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205

 if (npm.config.get('json')) {

 ^


 TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

 at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)

 at process.emit (events.js:189:13)

 at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:496:27)

Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(string sourcePath, string npmScriptName, ILogger logger)

Show raw exception details
System.InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm'

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

    at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:78:20
    at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:228:22)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:266:24
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:83:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:82:13
    at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:173:20)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:47:53
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205
  if (npm.config.get('json')) {
                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)
    at process.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:496:27)
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm'

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

    at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:78:20
    at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:228:22)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:266:24
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:83:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:82:13
    at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:173:20)
    at Conf.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:229:20)
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205

  if (npm.config.get('json')) {

                 ^


TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

    at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)

    at process.emit (events.js:189:13)

    at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:496:27)

 ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
```

Here Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I've installed lates nodejs version on server.
Where i'm wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show me th Backend code that serve angular app ?

Comment: @TonyNgo What code you want see ? The backend it's big.

Comment: What are you using for BE ? ASP.Net Core ? Node JS ?

Comment: Ah sorry, you're right...the backend it's C# .net core 2.1

Comment: Then upload the startup.cs for me I want to see it

Comment: @TonyNgo i've loaded Startup.cs in the question

Comment: I believe that you are self host in IIS so your .net core application cant find the npm of node js

Comment: @TonyNgo how can fix it ?

Comment: Hi .. Try to give admin user to appPool ..

Comment: I dont know how you host your code on your IIS so I really cant tell. But with this config your code should be good to run in local development

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi i've alredy set on appPool the admin permission

Comment: the problem looks like it can't create (mkdir) a folder .... so i think it's related to permission

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi i should set permission on the folder ?

Comment: mmm .but i looks strange .. if you're using an admin ..but you can give a try

Answer (score 4):

Try setting your environment to Production.  I think it has something to do with trying to do a NPM start

```
<environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Got a similar error but solved it by running the Application Pool Identity as `LocalSystem` instead of `IIS AppPool\...`. This enabled me to keep `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` as `Development` and thereby debug the code on an actual IIS.

My error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors
> occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the
> create-react-app server was listening for requests. The error output
> was: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir
> 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm'
>
> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir
> 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm'
>
> )) System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(bool
> includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>
> InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without
> indicating that the create-react-app server was listening for
> requests. The error output was: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted,
> mkdir 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm'
>
> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir
> 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm'
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer.ReactDevelopmentServerMiddleware.StartCreateReactAppServerAsync(string
> sourcePath, string npmScriptName, ILogger logger)

Answer (score 0):

Did following steps for me its is working **without** running **NPM start** on server.

- Go to web.config
- open and change the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT from **Development** to **Production**.
- Push your changes , this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Angular project template for VS 2019. I tried to refresh nodejs, set environment to "Production", comment spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start"); in Startup.cs - app was hanging on "Loading...". Nothing helped.

What helped is creating "npm" folder in C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming and assigning read permission for the folder to IIS_USR group.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing the environment variable in web.config file.
For Production environment you must change value of the variable "environmentVariable" in the file "web.config" in the project to be "Production". 
You can change it also in the publish profiles by adding the EnvironmentName Property {filename_environment}.pubxml:

```
<PropertyGroup>
 ...
 <EnvironmentName>Production</EnvironmentName>
</PropertyGroup>
```